# When connecting to Java socket, why does getInetAddress() return /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1?

Tags: java, sockets

I connect via MS Telnet which is where I see the output.

I know 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 would be ALL or wildcard... 
**but where does it come up with 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 ?**

What's the point of giving me this? Why not give me an IP such as 127.0.0.1?

Is this a virtual MAC address? Javadoc wasn't very informative.

> public InetAddress getInetAddress() Returns the address to which the
>   socket is connected. If the socket was connected prior to being
>   closed, then this method will continue to return the connected address
>   after the socket is closed.
>
> Returns: the remote IP address to which this socket is connected, or
>   null if the socket is not connected.
>   From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()

MAIN:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
/*
        * The actual work of the server socket is performed by an instance
        * of the {@code SocketImpl} class.
*/

        // Open a port to accept connections on 8080
        ServerSocket srvrSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

        // Block until someone connects
        while (true) {

            Socket socket = srvrSocket.accept();

            handle(socket);
        }
    }


    private static void handle(Socket socket) throws IOException {

        try(
                socket;
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                ) {

            // Print welcome
            DataUtil.writeStringAsInts(os, socket.getInetAddress().toString());
.
.
.
```

Comment: The localhost (loopback) address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, and the IPv6 unspecified address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, are reduced to ::1 and ::, respectively. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

Comment: Great answer. Can you add this as the answer?

Comment: this address representation is documented in [Inet6Address#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet6Address.html#format) or [RFC 2373: IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPV6 has representation of `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` for localhost, when we try to connect server socket from local, we may get `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` sometimes we may get `::1`

> The localhost (loopback) address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, and the IPv6
>   unspecified address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, are reduced to ::1 and ::,
>   respectively
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address